# Use vim as editor but emacs as code formatter

Tags: vim, emacs, erlang

As I see in erlang community common way to format code is how emacs erlang mode does.

Is there any way to call emacs to format code from vim (line, selected text, and hole file)?

Also I would appreciate if someone point me to some emacs docs, which describes this indent logic?

Edit: actually I know how to call something from vim, but i dont know what to call from emacs side.

Comment: No, there is no way to get emacs to format code in vim. But there are vim erlang plugins.

Comment: I will suggest you g through these 3 links :http://www.grok2.com/vi-emacs.html , http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs210/help/emacs.html, http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_unix.html. They were very helpful for me . However, i dunno whether we can call emacs from VIM.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I use vimerl, but it's formatting is different from emacs and my coworkers are not happy with it.

Comment: @Kent I satisfied with vim, but my coworkers which use emacs are not satisfied with how I format source code. They suggest me to call emacs to do this.

Comment: @danechkin consider using vim bindings within Emacs.  I hear evil-mode is very very good.

Comment: @event_jr Don't get me wrong, but I do not want to change my environment just to indent properly. Perhaps I could port indent logic to vim if I find how emacs does it?

Comment: Your question should be a lot more interesting if you added a sample of what you get with Vim, explaining how you got it and a sample of what you get with Emacs, explaining how you got it. And also clarify what you call "formatting".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intellij erlang plugin does exactly that : [ErlangEmacsFormatAction.java](https://github.com/ignatov/intellij-erlang/blob/master/src/org/intellij/erlang/actions/ErlangEmacsFormatAction.java)

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013 Sergey Ignatov
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */

final GeneralCommandLine commandLine = new GeneralCommandLine();
commandLine.setExePath("emacs");
commandLine.addParameters("--batch", "--eval");

String s = "\n" +
    "(progn (find-file \"{0}\")\n" +
    "    (require ''erlang-start)\n" +
    "    (erlang-mode)\n" +
    "    (untabify (point-min) (point-max))\n" +
    "    (delete-trailing-whitespace)\n" +
    "    (erlang-indent-current-buffer)\n" +
    "    (write-region (point-min) (point-max) \"{1}\")\n" +
    "    (kill-emacs))";

  commandLine.addParameter(MessageFormat.format(s, virtualFile.getCanonicalPath(), tmpFile.getCanonicalPath()));
```

It calls an emacs batch subprocess with the file as one of its arguments. It should be easy to implement something similar in vimscript, check [Vim External Commands](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/52.html).

Comment: Tried what you suggest me, from first look it is what I need, but now i see problems: 
1. this eval requires hole file, but not selected region (emacs returns: '(End of file during parsing)')
2. when I pass whole file emacs make from it one long line, and thats all

Comment: seems that 2nd problem is solved, I wrongly read file from stdin(\n was cutted), but 1st problem is remain.

Comment: Just create a temporary file, output the content of the selected region in that file, use emacs in batch mode on this file , and then spit back the content of the temporary file to replace your selected region. I can't help you with the vim code but I tested the whole thing in a bash script and it works perfectly.

Comment: I use [this script](https://gist.github.com/ddosia/5299338): `./ee.sh file.erl`, result output in gist's comments. Seems that everything went ok, but file is stay unmodified (i.e. with same formatting)

Comment: thanks mate! finally it works for me. I put final script [here](https://gist.github.com/ddosia/5299338#comment-810375)

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I know of that solves this problem is the vim plugin `vimerl`: https://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl

It's what I use, and while it's not perfect, it works reasonably well.

It would be great if it was completely consistent with Emacs indentation, but for the work it takes to get it running, it's a good start.

Comment: It could be too that the OP just needs to edit this plugin, perhaps even adding configuration options to control its behavior like the cindent stuff uses.  (See `:help cinoptions-values`)

Comment: Currently I use vimerl too, but it's sense of formatting differ from emacs one and this is a problem for my coworkers

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in looking into what [vim-erlang](https://github.com/vim-erlang) has to offer.